Resend API works perfect in localhost but not on my Netlify website
I have Resend API running in my Astro project, in which I send different forms towards my email with private domain. Everything is set in a json.ts file in which I perform the POST method to send the email.
In localhost is working perfectly but when I deploy my website in Netlify, I get an 500 error.
The API KEY is being obtained from an .env, with the method import.meta.env.API_RESEND, I have my doubts if this changes when my project is deployed in Netlify.
This is the code of my json.ts file:
import type { APIRoute } from 'astro'
import { Resend } from 'resend'

const resend = new Resend(import.meta.env.API_RESEND)

export const POST: APIRoute = async ({ request }) => {
    const body = await request.json()
    const { to, from, html, subject } = body

    if (!to || !from || !html || !subject) {
        return new Response(null, {
            status: 404,
            statusText: 'Did not provided the right data'
        })
    }

    try {
        const send = await resend.emails.send({
            from,
            to,
            subject,
            html
        })

        return new Response(
            JSON.stringify({
                message: send.data
            }),
            {
                status: 200,
                statusText: 'Email sent successfully'
            }
        )
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
        return new Response(
            JSON.stringify({
                message: err.message
            }),
            {
                status: 500,
                statusText: 'Internal server error'
            }
        )
    }


I fixed it already,
I was aiming to '/api/sendEmail.json.ts' when the correct way is '/api/sendEmail.json'
Thank you!
